# is Click event permanent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

You are asking what does permanent mean, I don't know either, it's just the most accurate to describe my situation.
I have this html button  :

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-follow="follow" 
        data-target="52cd6196211b6fc26a8b456c">

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  
      Follow
</button>
```

I added a click event as follows :

```
 $("button[data-follow=follow]").click(function(e) {//scenario1});
```

in a given case , this code gets executed :

```
 $("button[data-follow=follow]").attr("data-follow","unfollow");
```

and I have this listner :

```
$("button[data-follow=unfollow]").click(function(e) {//scenario2});
```

when I click on the button again it fires scenario1, when it should fire scenario2 ?

Does anybody know anything about what's happening ?

Comment: `$(..)` returns a *fixed* selection of elements. The click handler is added *that selection of elements*, in turn. (See event delegation, intercept the attribute changing, or skip handling the event ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then we have to use [`event-delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) at this context,

```
$(document).on('click',"button[data-follow=follow]",function(e) {//scenario1});

$(document).on('click',"button[data-follow=unfollow]",function(e) {//scenario2});
```

See i had suggested `document` to implement event delegation but you should use any closest static parent in relative to the supplied selector.

Comment: Do you suggest to use it on both scenarios ? 
I know it works as you suggest , but what is the best practice here ?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the attribute again you need to assign the click functionality

```
$("button[data-follow=follow]").attr("data-follow","unfollow");
immediate statement
$("button[data-follow=unfollow]").click(function(e) {//scenario2});
```

or you can use event deligation

```
$(document).on('click',"button[data-follow=follow]",function(e) {//scenario1});

$(document).on('click',"button[data-follow=unfollow]",function(e) {//scenario2});
```